# fatal error C1852:is not a valid precompiled header file

Tags: c++

I have seen all the articles on web, but nothing seems to resolve my issue.

Someone plz help me out on this.

I am using *debug* mode, **VS 2010, .net 4 Framework**.

In project properties, 
*CLR is on in general* 
*CLR in on in C++->general* 
*All **.cpp** files are having use (/yu) in precompiled hearder settings* 
***stdafx.cpp*** has /yc (create) with **clr** on

Answer (score 4):

I had the some problem.

Validate that all the C++ files properties (right click on the file in the solution explorer and Properties) are mark with "Common Language RunTime Support" as "/clr"

Comment: I'm darned if I know why these two files (out of the dozens in the project) happen to not have the /clr switch, but yup, that's the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you - this was the reason for me too. The /clr flag was off for the CLI file

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when another version of the compiler has created the PCH file or the PCH is corrupt. Try cleaning the solution or simply rebuilding.